# Texture to repeat and loop OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, texture-mapping

I have a simple scene I am creating, it is set on a planet and I want the appearance that the planet is spinning.

Currently I have texture mapped a quad with a star texture, then in DrawScene I translate the quad by X amount which translates the quad slowly to one side. The effect looks quite good for the level of detail I am looking for. The problem is that I cannot have an infinitely long quad with the repeated texture to give this effect, there comes a point when I will reach the end of my quad and then I will just have the background colour.

Is there a way to animate the Quad so that the repeated texture moves on the stationary quad perhaps? Or a simple way to achieve the effect I am looking for.

Comment: Two quick solutions I can think of. (1) Animate the UV coords, leaving the quad just where it is. (2) Texture-map the inside of a cylinder or sphere with the stars. Then rotate the sphere/cylinder _or_ just animate the camera lookAt vector. Here's an article that discussed yet another approach: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48983/The-wrapping-image-game-trick

Comment: I have achieved the effect by animating the UV coordinates for now. I think I will look at texture mapping the inside of a sphere/cylinder but I have only texture mapped quads in the past so will have to read up on this.

Comment: Just remembered this question when I was doing some reading earlier this morning. It's about the computation of vertices that make up a sphere, with the aim of making the calculation of UV coords (a) dead easy and (b) not susceptible to pinching or stretching at the poles - i.e each texel gets a similar amount of surface-area to cover. The site is a stunning wealth of information relating to openGL stuff. Though most of it goes straight above my puny head. :grin: Link: http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/patchedsphere/patchedsphere.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a textured cube or sphere for your star-scape and have the planet move around inside that, which would give the same effect but be able to continue infinitely.

There is an excellent tutorial at [**spieleprogrammierung.net**](http://www.spieleprogrammierung.net/2010/03/opengl-3-kameradrehung-hintergrund.html) for [`OpenGL`](http://www.khronos.org/opengl/) 3.3 and above, however you will need to translate the page (use chrome and it will do it for you) so you can read it in your own language.

Let me know if you need more information:)

Comment: I have achieved the effect by animating the texture co ordinates. This was seems a better solution though and I will need to look in more detail at how to texture map cylinders/spheres

Comment: effectively its the same, you map 6 textures to the quads that are the inside faces of a cube, and use the cube as your sky.  If the textures are made correctly, they will appear to be one continuous sky:)  I will make a tutorial and post it on my site if you like.  What version of OpenGL are you using/learning?

Comment: I am using 3.2.0. I have set it up with a rotating textured cube around my scene. It does give me the effect I am looking for so thank you!. I would like to learn how to do this for cylinders though as I have other ideas I would like to try.

Comment: closed end cylinder I take it or open ended?

Comment: That sounds great, Thanks! For my situation, open ended cylinder would be fine, although others may benefit from knowing a closed cylinder example.